# Django get specific QuerySet with GET ajax Call on button click

Tags: django, ajax, list, view, get

i have a problem and i dont know if im using the good way to solve it , but their is the problem , i have a client list that i show on the client page , by getting all client with a simple

```
clients = client.objects.all()
```

so all client can have a lot of sessions, and session have a lot of clients, its like a ManytoMany relation, so what im trynna do its to show the assigned session of client one by one by clicking on a button (the button open a boostrap modal ) , so i tried to send the id of the the chosen client on click and send it into a django view with ajax GET method, and take this ID directly to find all sessions related with this client and return the query to this page , so the ajax is working correctly and i can send the id , but its like the view its not sending anything . so their is my code hope you can help me :

Html (the div im inserting on the forloop client) :

```
<div class="list-group list-group-me">
<ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
<li class="list-group-item">{{ client.name }}</li> 
<li class="list-group-item">{{ client.email }}</li>
<li class="list-group-item">{{ client.created_at | date:" M Y" }}</li>
<li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Active</li>
<li class="list-group-item">025f55azg5</li> 
<li><div class="btn-group">
  
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="AddSession"
   data-id="{{ client.id }}">
Add
</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="{{ client.id }}" >View</button>
</div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

the view (tryin the .all() just to see if its working) :

```
class show_session(View):

def get(self, request , id):
    Sclient = session.objects.all()
    #Sclient = session.objects.filter(client__id=id)
    context = { 'Sclient': Sclient }

    

    return render(request, 'coach/addclient.html', { 'Sclient': Sclient })
```

the model.py :

```
class session(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
   client = models.ManyToManyField(client, blank=True)
   coach = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   detail = models.CharField(max_length=256)

   def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

the main view of the page :

```
def addclient(request):
form = ClientForm
clients = client.objects.filter(affiliation=request.user.id)
Csession = session.objects.filter(coach=request.user.id)

context = {'form': form ,'clients': clients , 'Csession' : Csession}

form = ClientForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ClientForm(request.POST)
    print(form)

    if form.is_valid():
        print('adding client 1133', form)
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        new_client = client.objects.create(name= name, email=email , affiliation=request.user)
        new_client.save()
        return JsonResponse({'client': model_to_dict(new_client)}, status=200)
    else:
        print('not adding client to the form 1333')
        return redirect('addclient')


return render(request, 'coach/addclient.html', context= context)
```

and the ajax function :

```
$("#AddSession").click(function(){


    var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(dataID)
    $.ajax({
    
        url:'addclient/'+ dataID +'/added',
        data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken,
        id: dataID
        },
        type : "get",

        success: function(response) {
            
            console.log("hey hey session over here");
 }

    })

});
```

i dont know if can use just the main view to get the data and display it , and when i try to acess the url of show_session.view , the query set is working but im still tryin to display it on the addclient url
thanks for your time and help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i have fixed the problem , i have just used a POST method to send the id of current user to the view then i used the action data attribute to handle multiple post on my view and use the id given by ajax to have the correct queryset and serialized the queryset into a JSON object so ajax can add the session assiciated with the choosen client on click their is the code :
View :

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['action'] == 'session':
    print("session response")
    id = request.POST.get('id')
    print(id)
    #Sclient = list(session.objects.filter(coach=request.user.id))
    Sclient = session.objects.filter(client__id=id)

    SerializedQuery = serializers.serialize('json', Sclient)
    return JsonResponse(SerializedQuery, safe=False)
```

Ajax :

```
$("#AddSession").click(function(){


    var dataID = $(this).data('id');
    
    $.ajax({
    
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrfToken,
        id: dataID,
        action: 'session',
        //dataType:"json"
        },
        type : "post",

        success: function(response) {
            
            console.log("hey hey session over here");
            console.log(response)
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response)
            //console.log(obj[1].fields.name)

            var Sarray = [];
            var Selector = $("#assigned");
            var count = $("#assigned span")

            console.log(count.length)

        //used to limit the number of element on div on first click
        
        if(count.length < obj.length)   
        {
            for (i = 0 ; i < obj.length ; i++) {
                // console.log(obj[i].fields.name)
                 Sarray.push(obj[i].fields.name)
                 Selector.append('<a href="#"><span class="badge badge-success">'+ obj[i].fields.name +' x </span></a>')
                }

                console.log("yoow",Sarray.length)
        }
            
 }

    })

});
```